# How to resignFirstResponder from a UITextView inside a UITableViewCell of a Static UITableView

Tags: xcode4.2

I have a very simple UITableView that was created inside a storyboard with "static cells". There are two sections, each containing one row. There is also a UIView for the table view header.

Section 0, Row 0, is a "Basic" style of UITableViewCell and performs a segue unrelated to my question.

Section 1, Row 0, is a Custom UITableViewCell that contains a UITextView.

This is working fine and becomes the first responder when selected. I also have an IBOutlet defined for this UITextView that allows me to work with it.

The thing I would like to do, is to resignFirstResponder from this view when the user taps outside of this scrollable UITextView.

I have searched all over and can't seem to find a way of doing this. Because it's inside a UITableView, I can't just make a large button behind the UITextView to perform the resignFirstResponder. I have even tried putting `[self.view endEditing:YES];` in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` for section 0, just to see if that would cause the UITextView to resignFirstResponder, but it just goes back to being selected after returning from the segue. Also, none of the UITextViewDelegate methods seems to be useful for this.

I am at a complete loss as to how I might actually get this UITextView to resignFirstResponder. Keep in mind that this is **not a UITextField** but a UITextView as I've read many other posts where similar questions have been asked and replies are given regarding a UITextField.

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated.